# Need a simple way to update the dynamic element database for JS to listen to events

Tags: javascript

When I want to listen to events on dynamically created elements via JS, I need to resort to listening to the events on the body to update the element list JS is listening to. Is there not a simple elegant way to update the element database for JS to listen to when I want?

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.className.toLowerCase() === 'demo-classes') {
        let closeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("demo-classes");
        Array.from(demoClasses).forEach(function (demoClass) {
            demoClass.addEventListener("click", function () {
                myArray.splice(demoClass.id.substring(2), 1);
                render(myArray);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

It leads to clicking two times, once on the body and another time on the element with the `demo-classes` class before the `splice` function removes the specific item from the arrays, then the `render` function renders the html. All `demo-classes` classes are generated using `createElement` and classes are set using the `setAttribute` in the `render` function.

Comment: Posting question without code will not take you anywhere.

Comment: @iftikharyk I hope the question is now proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `location.reload()` to refresh your page when you want to update the database of items in `getElementsByClassName` function. Store the variables and dynamically elements in Session Storage/Local Storage so that it survives browser refreshes.